# Mouse cursor disappears every time I visit YouTube or any video-related site

Tags: macbook-pro, mouse

Every time I visit YouTube (or any video-related site like Udemy) and watch a video, my mouse cursor disappears. It only becomes visible after a click. Is this a MacBook Pro 15" issue?

Has anyone experienced similar issues like these:
[Mouse cursor (pointer) disappears; invisible / missing; fix](https://appletoolbox.com/2015/10/mouse-cursor-pointer-disappears-invisible-missing-fix/)?

Are there better ways to workaround this bug?

Comment: Note that my current solution to this annoying bug is hitting the upper edge of the screen (seems >90% reliable). Clicking when you do not know where is dangerous. But my current workaround is also stupid since it often activates the hot corners. If that's the same for you: Maybe edit this as an almost reliable workaround that needs further improvement into your Q (Felt that it would've changed the Q too much.)

Comment: To anyone else dealing with this issue, which browsers are you using?